# How can I elegantly implement version checking in Python without throwing off indentation?

Tags: python

I'd like to very elegantly integrate version checking in Python.

I don't want a version checking routine to throw off the indentation of all of my code, however.

I.e.

```
if old_version:
   print 'hey, upgrade.'
else:
  # main body of whole script
```

In the above implementation, the main body of the whole script would need to be indented one level and that's just messy.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do

```
import sys

if old_version:
    print 'hey, upgrade.'
    sys.exit(1)  # A non-zero code indicates failure, on Unix (sys.exit() exits too, but it returns a 0 [=success] exit code)

# main body of whole script
```

This exits the interpreter if the code needs to be upgraded.

The reason for returning a non-zero exit code is that if your program is called from a Unix shell script and an upgrade is necessary, the shell will detect that there was problem and the user will know about it (instead of your program failing silently).

**PS**: As suggested in an answer which is now deleted, you can also do `sys.exit("hey, upgrade")`, instead.  This automatically returns an exit code of 1, as is appropriate.

Comment: D'oh. That makes sense. Thanks, EOL!

Answer (score 3):

This should only be a problem if you aren't putting your code in functions.

If you aren't putting your code in functions you should do that.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
if old_version:
    raise Exception ('Hey, upgrade')
```

?

Well, depending on if the upgrade is required or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just `sys.exit(0)`:

```
if old_version:
   print 'hey, upgrade.'
   sys.exit(0)
```

As Adam Vandenberg points out, a non-zero exit code will indicate failure to anything capturing the exit code. So that might be more appropriate.